# How to merge arrays of objects by Id key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, key

The function takes two array arguments and returns an array.

Arrays will contain objects representing some records.

The function must merge the two arrays into a new array under the following conditions:

- Copy objects with unique Id property values (i.e. objects with an Id value present in one array only).
- Merge objects with matching Id property values (i.e. objects with an Id value present in both arrays).
- Every object in the array will have an Id property.
- Original objects in both arrays must remain unchanged.

Merging objects means:

1. Where both arrays contain a record with the same Id property value, the result should contain a record with properties of both records.
2. Where both records have the same property name, use the value from the record in the second array.

```
const array1 = [
  { Id: 'a1' },
  { Id: 'a2', Name: 'Record 2', Cost: 4 } // Record a2 has Name and Cost properties
];

const array2 = [
  { Id: 'a2', Cost: 6 }, // Record a2 has a Cost property with a different value
  { Id: 'a3' }
];

const result = mergeArrays(array1, array2);

// Expected result
[
  { Id: 'a1' },
  { Id: 'a2', Name: 'Record 2', Cost: 6 }, // Name from array1 and Cost from array2
  { Id: 'a3' }
]
```

I have tried this:

```
function mergeArrays(array1, array2) {  

  let array3 = array1.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, array2[i]));
  
  return array3

}
```

But the result is 2 objects instead of 3:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {Id: 'a2', Cost: 6}
1: {Id: 'a3', Name: 'Record 2', Cost: 4}length: 2
```

Also this:

```
function mergeArrays(array1, array2) {  

  const result = array2.map(item => {
const searchedItem = array1.find(fItem => fItem['id'] === 
item['id'] );
if(searchedItem && Object.keys(searchedItem).length > 0 ){
  item['id'] = searchedItem['id']
}else{
   item['id'] = 'null'
}
 return item;
});
return result
}
```

But I keep receiving length = 2 when it should be 3.

I have tried everything that I found in here and can´t get it to return three objects as I should.

Comment: notice id does not exist in the dataset but Id  (uppercase I) does :)

Comment: also make it a practice to pass in the key you are looking for to the function, just to make it more generic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Idea:

using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) would be a better option here. so the idea is first feed data of `array2` into the `reduce()` as initial values. and then iterate through the `array1` and look any `Id` of `array1` already present in `acc` which holds values of `array2`. if `acc` has same `Id` that means we need to merge the entry with `acc[idx]` and update its old value. If it's not the case the two entries of `array1` and `array2` are unique so we need to push current item of `array1` to `acc` as `return [...acc, b]`.

```js
const array1 = [{Id: 'a1'},{ Id: 'a2', Name: 'Record 2', Cost: 4 }]; 
const array2 = [{ Id: 'a2', Cost: 6 }, { Id: 'a3' }];

const mergeArrays = (arr1, arr2) => {
  return arr1.reduce((acc, b) => {
    const idx = acc.findIndex(item => item.Id === b.Id); //look for the acc has the same id while iterating array1
    if (idx > -1) { // if found need to merge with value of array2
      acc[idx] = Object.assign(b, acc[idx]);
      return acc;
    }
    return [...acc, b]; //if we don't find anything so "b" is an unique entry
  }, arr2); //inital values of reduce is from array2

}


console.log(mergeArrays(array1, array2));
```

Comment: It does the exact job :) Could you please elaborate a little ? I´m learning and something here I don´t totally understand. Thanks in advance for your help Asraf!!

Comment: yes sure, I have added some comments and trying to write extra information as well.

Comment: thanks for your time Asraf, it helped a lot! really nice :)